# Python cannot connect to MySQL if declare in a class

Tags: python, mysql

I'm newbie in Python. I'm trying to use Python to connect MySQL Server. I wrote like guides from MySQL official page, it was OK. But, when I create a connector class, it raised the error "MySQL Connection not available"

Here is my class

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode

##  BEGIN MySQL Connector Class
class MySQLConnector :
    configs = {
        "user":"root",
        "password":"",
        "host":"127.0.0.1",
        "database":"python_db",
        "raise_on_warnings": True
    }
    cursor = None
    connection = None

    ##  BEGIN Constructor
    def __init__(self, configs = {}) :
        if(any(configs)!=False) :
            self.configs = configs
    ##  END Constructor

    ##  BEGIN Open
    def open(self) :
        try:
            self.connection = mysql.connector.connect(self.configs)
        except mysql.connector.Error as err:
            if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
                print("Something is wrong with your user name or password")
            elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
                print("Database does not exists")
            else:
                print(err)
        finally:
            self.connection.close()
        return self.connection
    ##  END Open

    ##  BEGIN close connection
    def close(self) :
        self.cursor.close()
        self.connection.close()
    ##  END close connection

    ##  BEGIN execute
    def execute(self, query) :
        if(self.connection == None) :
            print("Connection is None")
            return
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        if(self.cursor!=None) :
            self.cursor.execute(query)
        else:
            print("Cursor is 'None'")
    ##  END execute



##  END MySQL Connector Class

##  BEGIN RUN
objConnect = MySQLConnector()
objConnect.open()
objConnect.execute("SELECT * FROM User")
```

Please show me the way to solution and explained me why my code has error.

Thanks!

---

**EDITED**

Finally, mata and alecxe help me to solve this problem, I don't know which solution to be choosen. I summary here for someone has mistake like me:
1. Remove the finally statement.
2. Using `**` in `self.connection = mysql.connector.connect(**self.configs)`

Comment: `##  BEGIN MySQL Connector Class` ... `##  END MySQL Connector Class` - this makes any python programmer's eyes bleed.

Comment: `if(any(configs)!=False)` seems wrong to me, as the condition nearly always is true. What did you mean to accomplish?

Comment: @glglgl you'll find it difference when using this *objConnect = MySQLConnect(other_configs)*

Comment: @GiaDuongDucMinh Yes, but the way you write it seems suspicious to me. Did you just mean `if configs:` (testing if `configs is non-empty`)? Or `if any(configs):` (testing if it has at least one non-empty key)? What you do is testing if it has a value which evaluates to a tru-ish key (!) and compare that with `False`, which could never be the way except if it only has falsey values or is empty. So it is the same as `if any(configs):`, but very more complicated and very harder to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you correct the error alecxe pointed out, your code still won't work.

The `finally` block ensures that each connection is closed before it is returned, no matter wheather there was an exception or not, so the `open` method only returns closed connections.

Comment: Thank you! Your solution and alecxe's are fit for my problem.

Answer (score 3):

You are passing a dictionary object `self.configs` into `mysql.connector.connect`, though, according to [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html), you should pass to it `user`, `password` and other arguments. Looks like you need to unpack `configs`:

```
self.connection = mysql.connector.connect(**self.configs)
```

Hope this is it.

Comment: Thank you! Your solution and mata's are fit for my problem.